# Action button with select all in shiny tool of Rstudio

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I have the following shiny for a small shiny app. I have created the select all action button. Then how can I select all (A1, ..., C2) when I click "select all" button?

```
#ui script
library(shiny)
fluidPage(
    selectizeInput("select", "Select multiple", multiple = T, 
    choices = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2")),
    actionButton("selectall", "Select all:")
)
#server script
server <- function(input, output){
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
mychoices <- c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("campaigns", "Choose campaign(s):", multiple = T, choices = mychoices),
  actionButton("selectall", "Select all:")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$selectall,{
    if (input$selectall%%2 == 0){
      updateSelectInput(session,"campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",choices=mychoices)
    }
    else{
      updateSelectInput(session,"campaigns","Choose campaign(s):",choices=mychoices,selected=mychoices)
    }
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```